# Express Nodejs продакшн сервер

Tags: node.js, express

**Если сервер долго не трогать**, то **он встает с холодной перезагрузки**(подругому это называется с режима холостого хода). **Это все на локальной машине, при разработке**. Я боюсь такая же ситуация, будет в боевой среде. Как с этим бороться??

**Как я это понял?**

По morgan логеру.

В **документации express написано**

> Задать в переменной NODE_ENV значение “production”

**Возможно это решит проблему, но как это сделать?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Под Windows:

`SET NODE_ENV=production && node app.js`

Под Linux:

`export NODE_ENV=production && node app.js`

Если все сделано правильно, то в приложении `process.env.NODE_ENV` будет содержать `production`.

Если нужно задавать много переменных (например: порт, хост/логин/пароль от базы данных и т.д.), то можно использовать удобную библиотеку [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv). Тогда все эти данные будут храниться в `.env` файле, к примеру можно сделать два файла: для прода и для разработки